# How to get sibling and siblings attribute using selenium xpath

Tags: python, selenium

Based on the position of "CertainOption" found using xpath, how can I get the id of the sibling shown below. I appreciate any hint.

```html
<tr style="background-color:#EFF3FB;">
  <td align="center">
    <input id="OptionID" type="checkbox" name="OptionName">
  </td>
  <td align="center">CertainOption</td>
  <td align="left">Description</td>
</tr>
```

So far I wrote following working code:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("*//td[.//td[text()='CertainOption']]");
elements_sib = ???
siblings_att =  elements_sib.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@type='checkbox']").get_attribute('id');
```

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

```
#First, get element of interest    
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='CertainOption']")

#Second, get first preceding sibling  
elements_sibl = element.find_element_by_xpath("preceding-sibling::td[1]")

# Third, navigate to subfolder input and get attribute 
siblings_att = elements_sibl.find_element_by_xpath("input").get_attribute('id')
```

Thanks anyway